# Low Latency communication using web sockets & Java Server

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm looking to establish a low latency 2way communication between a javascript interface (client) and a java server.

The client has to request data from the server (can ask for different set's of data, needs to be async, data are small sets of sensor data).

I was thinking of implementing this using websockets because of it's low latency. However I'm stuck at choosing a java websocket server implementation (I found jetty but there are so many, and there is also a case to be made for node.js and socket.io but there are not going to be a lot of clients in this case; just one client sending multiple requests so correct me if i'm wrong but there doesn't seem to be a reason for going the node.js path).

Last but not least; the server is running on a raspberry pi and is recieving it's sensor data over a special protocol; (but i don't think that's important for this question).

Is there anyone with some experience in this field and wants to share his/her toughts? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using Atmosphere which is a framework that provides compatibility to all major java servers and web browsers. (The Java Official Standard is still in the workings).

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

I've got the chat demo up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Kaazing](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/) (HTML5 edition) to proxy traffic received via a web-socket to a Java process listening on a traditional TCP server socket.

It's working well, latency is low and was consistently handling over 1000 messages/second (though we found our Java code was the limiting factor in that respect).

[Kaazing](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/) also provides client APIs for Java, JavaScript and Flex, which allowed us to write an acceptance test suite using the familiar APIs (Concordion in my case).

I don't know how well it'd run on a Raspberry Pi, but given it's free to download there's a simple way to find out.

Comment: Here's [an example of using Kaazing on a RaspberryPi](https://kaazing.com/2013/04/01/remote-controlling-a-car-over-the-web-ingredients-smartphone-websocket-and-raspberry-pi/)